# Time out between scripts when executing a suite - Protractor Non Angular

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to run different specs in a suite which goes like this:

```js
  suites:{
        homepage: '../Phonebook/specs/Navigate_URL.js',
        Login:['../Phonebook/specs/Login_Valid.js',
                '../Phonebook/specs/Validate_Home.js'],
        search: '../Phonebook/specs/SearchText.js',
        logout: '../Phonebook/specs/Logout.js',
    },
```

When I run them separately using specs, all of them are running perfectly fine and no timing issues. I tried to run the whole suite at once and it ran perfectly fine and now, it shows that there's a timing issue again. I have included browser.sleep() in every script so just to make sure that all scripts will wait till the next script is being executed. getPageTimeout:, allScriptsTimeout: is also used. Is there any way or any general way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this a non-angular application under test, `Protractor` does not sync with it as it would do with Angular. The tests would not be as straight-forward and the flow would not be as clear and natural as it would be with an Angular app under test.

To avoid any timing issues, you need to always "look before you leap": use [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) with a set of built-in [Expected Conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions). For example, before making a search, wait for the search input to be visible:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    searchInput = element(by.id("search"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(searchInput), 5000, "Search input has not become visible");
```

Comment: Yes, I have already done these in my scripts. Or maybe I need to put another browser.wait before my next script is executed?

Comment: @Marj yeah, the idea is to put browser.waits in specific places, like, for example, in `beforeEach()` to wait for a page to be completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, though I think it is just a temporary solution, I included browser.sleep in every script before the next script is being executed, it works temporarily.